# Inserting an element at the first position in every individual list of a list of a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a simple problem. I need to insert an element from a list at the first position of every individual list, of a list of a list.

I tried it using the code mentioned below but it doesn't give the required_output

```
for i in bank_name_list:
    for j in dummy_list:
        j.insert(0,i)
print(dummy_list)
```

> bank_name_list = ['Bank1', 'Bank2']
>
> dummy_list = [[2,4,5],[5,6,8]]
>
> actual_output = [['Bank2', 'Bank1', 2, 4, 5], ['Bank2', 'Bank1', 5, 6, 8]]
>
> required_output = [['Bank1',2,4,5],['Bank2',5,6,8]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```py
bank_name_list = ['Bank1', 'Bank2']
dummy_list = [[2,4,5],[5,6,8]]
bank_name_list
for index, sub_list in enumerate(dummy_list):
    sub_list.insert(0,bank_name_list[index])

print(dummy_list)
```

**Output**:

```py
[['Bank1', 2, 4, 5], ['Bank2', 5, 6, 8]]
```

But this approach works only if both `bank_name_list` and `dummy_list` have same length

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip`

**Ex:**

```
bank_name_list = ['Bank1', 'Bank2']
dummy_list = [[2,4,5],[5,6,8]]

result = []
for bank, dummy in zip(bank_name_list, dummy_list):
    result.append([bank] + dummy)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Bank1', 2, 4, 5], ['Bank2', 5, 6, 8]]
```

Comment: Please accept(tick symbol) any one of the ans that solved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple and pythonic, try this out:

```
bank_name_list = ['Bank1', 'Bank2']
dummy_list = [[2,4,5],[5,6,8]]
output = []
for item in zip(bank_name_list, dummy_list):
    output.append([item[0],*item[1]])

print(output)
```